# useEffect old data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Studing react hooks I faced a problem and I don't understand what is happening. My idea is make a list of numbers that can be incremented and this list should be always decrementing. What happen is when I add a high value first it goes to the end of list and just reorganize when I type something new or increment a number, but if I print the array in console it is alredy organized. How to fix this and what is really happening ?

Follow my code bellow:

```
function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [id, setId] = useState(0)
  const [inputText, setInputText] = useState('')

  useEffect(() => {
    setData(data => data.sort((a, b) => b.count - a.count));
  }, [data])

  function handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    setData(data => [...data, { id: id, count: inputText}])
    setInputText('')
    setId(id + 1);
  }

  function handleAdd(id) {
    setData(data => data.map(e => e.id !== id ? e : ({ ...e, count: e.count + 1 })))
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={(e) => handleSubmit(e)} >
        <input type="number" onChange={e => setInputText(parseInt(e.target.value))} value={inputText} />
        <button>Submit</button>
      </form>
      {
        wordList.map(
        (item) =>
          <div>
            <p>{item.count}</p>
            <button onClick={() => handleAdd(item.id)}>+</button>
          </div>
        )
      }
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Examples:
The array starts empty and after add number 2:

```
[
  {id:0, count:2}
]
```

Then after add a higher number the array should to reorganizer to be decrescent like this

```
[
  {id:1, count:3},
  {id:0, count:2}
]
```

And this is happening but just update the DOM if interact with something

[gif to show](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aWYeM.jpg)

Comment: Your description is a little bit difficult to follow. Could you maybe update it with step-by-step examples? Like, step 1 initial array: `[0,6,8,2,9]` or something?

Comment: [`sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) mutates the original array. This could lead to unexpected behavior since you're mutating state.

Comment: I added some new informations

Comment: What is happening is a render followed by a sort now the sort won't be visible until the next re-render, when you hit submit a number gets added to `data` then a render is triggered after that useEffect get triggered which sort the array but there's no re-render after that and when you try to type something in the input it cause a re-render because of `setInputText` i suggest you sort before you changing the state

Answer (score 0):

Please update setData function:

```
setData(data => [...data, { id: id, count: inputText } ] );

setData(data => data.sort((a, b) => b.count - a.count));

setData(data => data.map(e => e.id !== id ? e : ({...e, count: e.count+1})))
```